# Compute emitted importance of a pinhole camera

Tags: raytracing, physically-based, camera

In [section 16.1.1 of *Physically Based Rendering*](https://books.google.de/books?id=iNMVBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA950&lpg=PA950&dq=%22for+pinhole+apertures,+we+compute%22&source=bl&ots=ivwhEhZqRF&sig=yCpEAaOMpYlA9Vj-LykM5_VHnoQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvirbRlM7dAhXFzaQKHW2KB3EQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22for%20pinhole%20apertures%2C%20we%20compute%22&f=false) the authors describe how we can check, if a given ray $r$ corresponds to one starting from the film area.

They implement this check such that it works for cameras with finite and pinhole apertures. They assume that $r$ has origin $p$ and direction $\omega$. Maybe I didn't get it, but are they assuming that $p$ is a point on the lens? That seems to be the case from Figure 16.1.

Now they want to find the point on the film that $r$ corresponds to. Let $w$ denote the camera viewing direction $(0,0,1)$ in world coordinates. Then they compute the cosine of the angle $\theta$ between $\omega$ and $w$, $$\cos(\theta)=\langle\omega,w\rangle.$$ Assuming we're dealing with a pinhole aperture, why do we find the point on the film by intersecting the ray with a plane arbitrary set at $z=1$? And why is this intersection at $p+t\omega$, where $t=1/\cos(\theta)$? Shouldn't the intersection be at $t=\frac{\langle w-p,w\rangle}{\langle\omega,w\rangle}$?

And anyway, doesn't $p$ need to be equal to the eye point of the camera?